# Email Generator iteration through a list

Tags: c#, list, iteration, ienumerable

I've written a function that generates an HTML email and fills it with information from a database.

I've been trying to iterate through a list, but can't seem to get the function to be generic and run throught the Items list.

Here is the Email Generator function. It is fairly generic, so that it can be used in a wide variety of email templates.

```
    public interface IMailObject
    {
        string Subject { get; }
    }

    public interface IEmailGenerator
    {
        MailMessage generateEmail(IMailObject mailObject, string htmlTemplate, string textTemplate);
    }

    public class EmailGenerator : IEmailGenerator, IRegisterInIoC
    {   
        private string mergeTemplate(string template, object obj)
        {
            Regex operationParser = new Regex(@"\$(?:(?<operation>[\w\-\,\.]+)\x20)(?<value>[\w\-\,\.]+)\$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Regex valueParser = new Regex(@"\$(?<value>[\w\-\,\.]+)\$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

            var operationMatches = operationParser.Matches(template).Cast<Match>().Reverse().ToList();
            foreach (var match in operationMatches)
            {
                string operation = match.Groups["operation"].Value;
                string value = match.Groups["value"].Value;
                var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(value);
                if (propertyInfo == null)
                    throw new TillitException(String.Format("Could not find '{0}' in object of type '{1}'.", value, obj));

                object dataValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);

                if (operation == "endforeach")
                {
                    string foreachToken = "$foreach " + value + "$";
                    var startIndex = template.LastIndexOf(foreachToken, match.Index);
                    var templateBlock = template.Substring(startIndex + foreachToken.Length, match.Index - startIndex - foreachToken.Length);
                    var items = (IEnumerable) value;

                    string blockResult = "";

                    foreach (object item in items)
                    {
                        blockResult += mergeTemplate(templateBlock, item);
                    }

                    template = template.Remove(startIndex, match.Index - startIndex).Insert(startIndex, blockResult);
                }
            }

            var valueMatches = valueParser.Matches(template).Cast<Match>().Reverse().ToList();
            foreach (var match in valueMatches)
            {
                string value = match.Groups["value"].Value;
                var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(value);
                if (propertyInfo == null)
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("Could not find '{0}' in object of type '{1}'.", value, obj));

                object dataValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);

                template = template.Remove(match.Index, match.Length).Insert(match.Index, dataValue.ToString());
            }

            return template;
        }

        public MailMessage generateEmail(IMailObject mailObject, string htmlTemplate, string textTemplate)
        {
            var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.Subject = mailObject.Subject;
            mailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            // Create the Plain Text version of the email
            mailMessage.Body = this.mergeTemplate(textTemplate, mailObject);

            // Create the HTML version of the email
            ContentType mimeType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html");

            AlternateView alternate = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(this.mergeTemplate(htmlTemplate, mailObject), mimeType);
            mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(alternate);

            return mailMessage;
        }
    }
```

And here is a case of the message data:

```
    public class MessageData : IMailObject
    {
        public string Property1 { get; private set; }
        public string Property2 { get; private set; }
        public string Property3 { get; private set; }
        public string Property4 { get; private set; }
        public string Property5 { get; private set; }
        public string Property6 { get; private set; }
        public string Subject
        {
            get { return this.Property1 + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(); }
        }
        public List<MessageItemData> Items { get; private set; }

        public MessageData(string property1, string property2, string property3, DateTime property4, string property7, string property8, DateTime property9, DateTime property10, int property11, double property12, string property5, string property6)
        {
            this.Property1 = property1;
            this.Property2 = property2;
            this.Property3 = property3;
            this.Property4 = property4.ToShortDateString();
            this.Property5 = property5;
            this.Property6 = property6;

            this.Items = new List<MessageItemData>();
            this.Items.Add(new MessageItemData(property7, property8, property9, property10, property11, property12));
        }
    }

    public class MessageItemData
    {
        public string Property7 { get; private set; }
        public string Property8 { get; private set; }
        public string Property9 { get; private set; }
        public string Property10 { get; private set; }
        public int Property11 { get; private set; }
        public double Property12 { get; private set; }

        public MessageItemData( string property7, string property8, DateTime property9, DateTime property10, int property11, double property12)
        {
            this.Property7 = property7;
            this.Property8 = property8;
            this.Property9 = property9.ToShortDateString();
            this.Property10 = property10.ToShortDateString();
            this.Property11 = property11;
            this.Property12 = property12;
        }
    }
```

The function works when there is only one set of elements being used. If we use the MessageData class as an example. All the information will be replaced correctly, but I'm wanting to improve the email generator function, because this particular MessageData class has a list of objects, where Property7 to Property12 will be replaced multiple times.

The function is started at: if (operation == "endforeach"), but I need some help to improve it so that it runs through the: var items = (IEnumerable) value;, so that the function returns TemplateHeader + TemplateItem + TemplateItem + ...however many TemplateItems there are + TemplateFooter. It currently will only return TemplateHeader + TemplateItem + TemplateFooter, even though there are multiple items in the list, it will only return the first item.

In this case I'm assuming I need to get the List Items. I've been trying to implement it into the EmailGenerator just below:

```
var items = (IEnumerable) value;
```

with the code:

```
if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(List<>))
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Console.WriteLine is just for testing purposes, to see if I get any values in Debug(which I'm currently getting null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the type of the **Items** property is the same across all instances you may want to try using **IsInstanceOfType** instead. And then get the value of the property via the **GetValue** method. Reflection can be confusing at times ;) but hopefully, it is what you are looking for.

```
var data = new MessageData("a", "b", "c", DateTime.Now, "d", "e", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, 1, 2, "f", "g");
data.Items.Add(new MessageItemData("7", "8", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, 11, 12));
data.Items.Add(new MessageItemData("71", "81", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, 111, 112));

var dataType = data.GetType();
foreach (var propertyInfo in dataType.GetProperties())
{
    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsInstanceOfType(data.Items))
    {
        foreach (var item in (List<MessageItemData>)propertyInfo.GetValue(data))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```